# Changing simpleVRML file name ERROR

Tags: c, xcode, macos, plist, artoolkit

i made some modifications in simpleVRML file in artoolkit for  Mac OS X but when i change the executable name for the app

[image: changing executable name]

and copy/paste my app to another folder, it gives me this error
[image: error]
but when it change the name back to simpleVRML, then copy/paste no error, what could be the error? 
Any help, i really dont want to show my app as simpleVRML :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem its is i change de executable name in plist i should also change the name of unix executable file inside the Macos folder of the app. :) my bad